# Laravel why record is not updating using vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3

i am trying to update text when i send request to Laravel controller, but i am getting error:

```
500 internal server error 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

**console.log** is showing text and values which i am trying to send to controller:

```
id:16 text:aa
```

**vue js code:**

```
const onEdit=(todo)=>{
    //  var src = evt.target.innerHTML
    //  this.txt = src
    axios
        .put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/update', {
            id:todo.id,
            text:todo.text
        })
        .then(() => getTodos());

    console.log("working", todo.text, todo.id);
};
```

**Laravel COntroller:**

```
public function updateData(Request $request)
{
    $todo = Todo::find($request->id);
    $todo->update($request->all());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'updated'
    ]);
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::put('todo/update',[TodoController::class,'updateData']);
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Todo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['id'];
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

i checked laravel log and i got error:

```
Add [id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Todo].
```

Then i added id in model. now i am seeing below response in console log but it is not updating data.

[image]

Comment: try  $todo->update(['text'=>$request->text]); instead of   $todo->update($request->all());

Comment: record not updating using it

Comment: can you show Todo model code

Comment: added model in question.

Comment: remove fillable property protected $fillable = ['id']; and add protected $guarded=['id'];

Comment: Thankyou it's working, how can i update multiple fields with request all or i will have to write each column name like you did.

Comment: try all () it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with Todo Model,where you allowed `id` field as fillable. Since id is auto increment filed in database .So text field should be fillable.

```
  protected $fillable = ['id'];
```

so here you have two options .One is to allow `$fillable` property to `text` field  or guarding id property so all other properties are fillabe

So

```
 protected $guarded=['id'];
```

or

```
protected $fillable=['text'];
```

Answer (score 2):

A 500 error is a generic server side error.

Firstly, edit your onEdit function to add a `catch` so you can console log the server error.

```js
const onEdit = (todo) => {
  axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/update', {
    id: todo.id,
    text: todo.text
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    getTodos()
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
};
```

Once you know what the server error is then you'll know what to fix.

Comment: added snippet under

Comment: Ok that's not any help. You'll need to check your Laravel logs too.

Comment: Now the data is not updating - this means that your `getTodos()` functions likely isnt working properly. If you console log the response data from getTodos does it contain your updated todo?

Comment: i can't see updated data in sql aswell

Comment: There must be something wrong with your ` $todo->update` statement.